# How much should I enforce the concept of entity and value object in DDD?

Tags: c#, design-patterns, architecture, domain-driven-design

I am working on a C# project using DDD. I wrote some classes. Some fall into the entity category, other fall into the value objects category. My question is, how much work must, or should I have to do in order to be true to the definitions of entities and value objects ?

Entities :

- Public constructor forbidden. Must use factory and/or static method, so uniqueness of object (in memory with id) is guaranteed.
- Operators ==, != overloading, and Equals method overriding, so comparison is based on something else than object reference ; an id

Value objects :

- Public constructor allowed. Factory, static method are allowed, and could implement some sort of caching, in order to (optionally) guarantee uniqueness of object (like string interning).
- Operator ==, != overloading, and Equals method overriding, so comparison is based on all values of both objects. Struct could also be used, instead.
- Immutable

These are possibilities than could enforce the concepts, but, are those mandatory ? Because making those factories, those static methods, overloading and overriding all those methods seems a huge load or work for a small amount, applying DDD concepts.

How far should I go ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a programming principle which I love, It's called [KISS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle).

The bottom line is to go as far as you need to, don't just do things and follow guidelines just because you have heard of, or came across them. Instead start with basic functionality and keep adding stuff as you need them.

For example, you talked about factories. I usually don't use them unless object creation is complex or i want to enforce certain conditions, or when you talked about operator overloading for comparison, I don't do that unless i need to actually do comparison or need it in my code. One thing i do apply when I could is Immutability and not just because it is suitable for Value Objects but also because it is a great tool when it comes to multi-threading support because immutable objects can't be modified after the are created.

**Summary:** start simple and add things as you need them.

Comment: So, for value objects, you apply immutability, but you do not override or overloading anything until you need it ? You strictly adhere to the KISS principle ?

Comment: @DavidKhuu Overall yes, i don't like the *strictly* word but yes i try to add things as i need them or if i found out from requirement analysis that i definitely will need them in the future. To tell you the truth i learned from my mistakes and so will you.

Answer (score 1):

Start simple and evolve.

For example:
Let's say I have an entity PendingOrder, I started it with:

Application Layer:

```
@Transactional
@Override
public PendingOrder placeOrder(Address deliveryAddress, Date deliveryTime) {
    PendingOrder pendingOrder = new PendingOrder(
            pendingOrderRepository.nextTrackingId(), deliveryAddress,
            deliveryTime);     //by constructor
    pendingOrderRepository.store(pendingOrder);
    return pendingOrder;
}
```

Later when the client required to validate whether there is available restaurant for the delivery infomation, I introduced PendingOrderFactory to enforce some domain constraints:

Application Layer:

```
@Transactional
@Override
public PendingOrder placeOrder(Address deliveryAddress, Date deliveryTime) {
    PendingOrder pendingOrder = pendingOrderFactory.placeOrderWith(
            deliveryAddress, deliveryTime);//refactor to factory
    pendingOrderRepository.store(pendingOrder);
    return pendingOrder;
}
```

Domain Layer:

```
public PendingOrder placeOrderWith(Address deliveryAddress,
        Date deliveryTime) {

    if (restaurantRepository.isAvailableFor(deliveryAddress, deliveryTime)) {
        return new PendingOrder(pendingOrderRepository.nextTrackingId(),
                deliveryAddress, deliveryTime);
    } else {
        throw new NoAvailableRestaurantException(deliveryAddress,
                deliveryTime);
    }

}
```

on the other hand, some code generation tool could be used. This is what we use in java

```
@ToString(of = "trackingId") //print PendingOrder.trackingId
@EqualsAndHashCode(of = "trackingId")//compare trackingId when Equals
public class PendingOrder {// this is an entity

@ToString //print all fields
@EqualsAndHashCode //compare all fields
@NoArgsConstructor
// @NoArgsConstructor for frameworks only
public class Address {// this is a value object
```

And still, we only add them when necessary, usually, @ToString is needed when you write tests to report explict error, @EqualsAndHashCode is needed when you write tests using mocks.

For example: pendingOrderFactory is a mock, we verify it is invoked with given arguments(deliveryAddress, deliveryTime), the mock framework check this by Equals, and when we fail to satisfy the expecation, a report is shown. the mock framework invokes ToString to indicate which object break the expecation.

```
@Test
public void placesAPendingOrder() throws Exception {
    final PendingOrder pendingOrder = new PendingOrderFixture().build();
    final Address deliveryAddress = pendingOrder.getDeliveryAddress();
    final Date deliveryTime = pendingOrder.getDeliveryTime();

    context.checking(new Expectations() {
   {
            allowing(pendingOrderFactory).placeOrderWith(deliveryAddress,
                    deliveryTime);//need to implement equals
            will(returnValue(pendingOrder));

            oneOf(pendingOrderRepository).store(pendingOrder);//need to implement equals
        }
    });

    PendingOrder order = target.placeOrder(deliveryAddress, deliveryTime);

    assertThat(order, is(pendingOrder));
}
```

Hope this helps and sorry for Java example 'cause I'm a C# idiot :(